# How to format the markdown for Outlook email in Office 365?

Tags: email, outlook, office365, markdown

I would like to use markdown format to make my email more compact.

I tried `[link](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16911154-markdown-support)`. But the link can still be seen in the email. How to properly achieve link markdown?

Answer (score 6):

Outlook doesn't support Markdown. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/markdown-support-in-outlook/74cd161c-b3bb-4a91-9aa6-2e23c13da475